# Google play services not working in x86 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-googleapiclient

I am using Google plus login in my app. For this I've added dependency 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'`
in build.gradle. I am using emulator with api 19 with arm system image. It works fine on this emulator. But I tried the same in another system with x86 emulator . But it shows the message `this app won't run without google play services`. My sdk is updated with latest version of Google apis and Goggle x86 System image. But still it shows update message and I am not able to run app on this emulator. What is the problem here?

Comment: The two emulator images for API 19 with Google APIs that I see are called  "Google APIs (ARM System Image)" and "Google APIs (x86 System Image)". Can you confirm that these are indeed the ones you are using in your two emulators? Did you do any special customization to your ARM emulator? I am actually more surprised that play-services-plus is supported on your ARM emulator than that it does not work on x86.

Comment: Yes , for me it works only in this system image. [this is my emulator configuration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L7xcA.png)  and this is [my sdk platform](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CDRgy.png). I tried in many versions of x86 system image, but doesn't work

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using your own phone to test? Anyways if you that is not an option. Please try to use Genymotion emulator instead:

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

I wouldn't really consider using the android built-in x86 emulator because it is really really crappy. HAHA! Hope this helps :)